# NPM release module not detecting git repository

Tags: npm, release, semantic-versioning, monorepo

When I am running "release pre beta" on root project. existing project support mono repo structure. It gives me below error. But actually I have the .git folder on my root.

> [before-after-hook]: "Hook()" repurposing warning, use "Hook.Collection()". Read more: https://github.com/gr2m/before-after-hook/tree/d1e515fbc106f6130c9a644a26c711ff7bb75a9d#upgrading-to-14
>
> √ Bumped version tag to 0.1.3-alpha.1
>
> √ Created release commit
>
> √ Tagged commit
>
> √ Pushed everything to remote
>
> Error! Directory is not a Git repository.
> error Command failed with exit code 1.
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Or there is any option to prevent push using release module.

[Module Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/release)

Answer (score 0):

This is the existing defect with npm release module. it does not work on windows.

Linux/Mac i have tried it is working fine.

[defect link](https://github.com/zeit/release/issues/129)